# Set width SeekBar Android

Tags: java, android, android-seekbar, android-vertical-seekbar

I'm using VerticalSeekBar and I would like to set the width.
With the term width I mean the width of the seekbarbar progress part.
This is my xml

```
<com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnDate"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp">
            <com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/verticaleDate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:seekBarRotation="CW270"
            android:max="10"
            android:splitTrack="false"/>
    </com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper>
```

Thanks for interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**background_fill.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#FF555555"
        android:endColor="#FF555555"
        android:startColor="#FF555555" />

    <corners android:radius="1dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#50999999" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#70555555" />

</shape>
```

**progress_fill.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#FFB80000"
        android:endColor="#FFFF4400"
        android:startColor="#FF470000" />

    <corners android:radius="1dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#50999999" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#70555555" />

</shape>
```

**progress.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/background_fill"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/progress_fill" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**thumb.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#E5492A"
        android:startColor="#E5492A" />

    <size
        android:height="20dp"
        android:width="20dp" />

</shape>
```

Update your seekbar layout by this:

```
<com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnDate"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

    <com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/verticaleDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
        app:seekBarRotation="CW270"
        android:max="10"
        android:splitTrack="false"/>

</com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! how can i have the thumb with the same style?

Comment: it work perfectly, but what is the property that define the size? i tried to set 3dp in background_fill and progress_fill but the size not changed

Comment: @Davide Change the stroke width.

Comment: why if i increase the dp the width is less?

Comment: I didn't get you.

Comment: if i increase the width value the width of seek is less than the value is lower